# Trivial "+[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:block:]: unrecognized selector" error

Tags: cocoa, nstimer

I am banging my head against an odd error after a move to 10.12/Sierra and Xcode 8.1:

```
+[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:block:]: 
     unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff78f1fa88
```

The most minimal code (default settings of create a new project) to reproduce this is:

```
//  AppDelegate.m
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer * timer;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 
                           repeats:YES 
                             block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) 
   {
        NSLog(@"Ping from %@", timer);
    }];
}
```

The linking includes the (Core)Foundation classes and 'all_load'. Must be something totally trivial - but fail to what it is.

Any and all help appreciated.

Thanks,

Dw.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, that code does not crash for me (10.12.1, Xcode 8.1).

Answer (score 31):

+[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:block:] is an iOS 10.0+ method. Are you maybe trying to run it on iOS 9.x?

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstimer/2091889-scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval?language=objc

Comment: You can check if the new method exists with the following code and fallback to an older API if need be.
if ([[NSTimer class] respondsToSelector:@selector(scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:block:)]) {
..
}

Comment: I was wondering why I am facing this weird crash only on 9.x device. Thank you Alessandro

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer/2091888-timerwithtimeinterval?language=objc

     if ([self.timer respondsToSelector:@selector(scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:‌​repeats:block:)]) { 
          // Code for iOS 10.0+ 
        } else { 
          // Code for IOS version lower than 10.0 
        }

Comment: This just cost me an expedited review. Normally XCode produces a warning if you include code only available in an iOS version newer than your target... but not this.