# Unhandled Exception: Foundation.MonoTouchException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> occurred

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, timer, crash, nstimer

I'm using Xamarin Forms and am seeing this problem only on an iPad Mini 1st generation (iOS 9.3.3 (13G34)).

The app starts up fine, clicking stuff works fine. The only problem happens when I "tap and hold" on a button, causing it to crash.

Probably the important part piece of the error message is this:

```
+[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:block:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3b101ed4
```

Unhandled Exception: Foundation.MonoTouchException:

Now this [SO answer][1] states that NSTimer is an iOS10+ API, hence iOS9 would not be supported.

My question is how do I fix it in a Xamarin Forms environment?

Thanks.

Full Error Message Text:

---

```
2018-10-18 14:31:25.805 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] +[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:block:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3b101ed4
Unhandled Exception:

Foundation.MonoTouchException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #10
The thread 0xa has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #13
The thread 0xd has exited with code 0 (0x0).
2018-10-18 14:31:47.340 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] 
Unhandled Exception:
0   MyApp.iOS                       0x05941e01 setup_stack_trace + 128
1   MyApp.iOS                       0x0594017f mono_handle_exception_internal + 2026
2   MyApp.iOS                       0x0593f991 mono_handle_exception + 50
3   MyApp.iOS                       0x05937837 mono_arm_throw_exception + 118
4   MyApp.iOS                       0x0085ac4c throw_exception + 64
5   MyApp.iOS                       0x05a88390 xamarin_process_managed_exception_gchandle + 60
6   MyApp.iOS                       0x05a8834c xamarin_ftnptr_exception_handler + 24
at (wrapper native-to-managed) ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception (intptr) [0x00025] in <572357c3f84340a29e439dbdac7629bd#91B547D7-180F-9262-A1A8-072C01C70687>:0
8   MyApp.iOS                       0x05a86228 xamarin_throw_ns_exception + 52
9   MyApp.iOS                       0x05a892b4 _ZL17exception_handlerP11NSException + 288
10  CoreFoundation        
              0x24157c57 <redacted> + 642
11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x238f309f <redacted> + 174
12  libc++abi.dylib                     0x238e4e17 <redacted> + 78
13  libc++abi.dylib                     0x238e48f9 __cxa_increment_exception_refcount + 0
14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x238f2f5f objc_exception_rethrow + 42
15  CoreFoundation                      0x240672af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 654
16  CoreFoundation                      0x24067015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
17  GraphicsServices                    0x25657ac9 GSEventRunModal + 160
18  UIKit                               0x2873b189 UIApplicationMain + 144
at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) [0x0004f] in <572357c3f84340a29e439dbdac7629bd#91B547D7-180F-9262-A1A8-072C01C70687>:0
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:80
at UIKit.UIApplication
.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00034] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:64
at MyApp.iOS.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00001] in C:\Projects\MyProject\MyApp\MyApp.iOS\Main.cs:17
at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0001e] in <7d5a05cfcb09432d8cc656b9d781e54b#91B547D7-180F-9262-A1A8-072C01C70687>:0
24  MyApp.iOS                       0x0594c9c9 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 824
25  MyApp.iOS                       0x059b6eef mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 102
26  MyApp.iOS                       0x059bb6db mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 66
27  MyApp.iOS                       0x05934141 mono_jit_exec + 198
28  MyApp.iOS                       0x05a9d174 xamarin_main + 2452
29  MyApp.iOS                       0x002388bd main + 102
30  libdyld.dylib                       0x23d0f873 <redacted> + 2
2018-10-18 14:31:47.344 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] Unhandled managed exception:
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: +[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:block:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3b101ed4
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x24157933 <redacted> + 150
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x238f2e17 objc_exception_throw + 38
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x2415d1d1 <redacted> + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x2415aee1 <redacted> + 700
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x24086238 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
    5   MyApp.iOS                       0x02ae4e68 wrapper_managed_to_native_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_Double_bool_IntPtr_intptr_intptr_double_bool_intptr + 156
    6   MyApp.iOS                       0x025eb030 Foundation_NSTimer_CreateScheduledTimer_double_bool_System_Action_1_Foundation_NSTimer + 276
    7   MyApp.iOS                       0x058b39ec MyApp_Forms
_Controls_ExtendedButtonRenderer_OnLongPressed_UIKit_UILongPressGestureRecognizer + 1468
    8   MyApp.iOS                       0x0286d720 UIKit_UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Callback_Activated_UIKit_UILongPressGestureRecognizer + 52
    9   MyApp.iOS                       0x008014a4 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 232
    10  MyApp.iOS                       0x0594c9c9 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 824
    11  MyApp.iOS                       0x059b6eef mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 102
    12  MyApp.iOS                       0x059b9ac1 mono_runtime_invoke + 56
    13  MyApp.iOS                       0x001e7119 _ZL32native_to_managed_trampoline_212P11objc_objectP13objc_selectorPP11_MonoMethodP28UILongPressGestureRecognizerj + 326
    14  MyApp.iOS                       0x001e6fcf -[__UILongPressGestureRecognizer target:] + 50
    15  UIKit                               0x28c389eb <redacted> + 142
    16  UIKit                               0x2887384f <redacted> +
 170
    17  UIKit                               0x28704ff1 <redacted> + 1004
    18  UIKit                               0x28c39d4f <redacted> + 62
    19  UIKit                               0x286c5a57 <redacted> + 298
    20  UIKit                               0x286c2017 <redacted> + 2902
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x241196c9 <redacted> + 20
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x241179cd <redacted> + 280
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x24117dff <redacted> + 958
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x24067229 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x24067015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x25657ac9 GSEventRunModal + 160
    27  UIKit                               0x2873b189 UIApplicationMain + 144
    28  MyApp.iOS                       0x02bc227c wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 288
    29  MyApp.iOS                       0x02412044 UIKit_UIApplication_Main_stri
ng___intptr_intptr + 52
    30  MyApp.iOS                       0x02411edc UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 200
    31  MyApp.iOS                       0x0023acb0 MyApp_iOS_Application_Main_string__ + 152
    32  MyApp.iOS                       0x008014a4 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 232
    33  MyApp.iOS                       0x0594c9c9 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 824
    34  MyApp.iOS                       0x059b6eef mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 102
    35  MyApp.iOS                       0x059bb6db mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 66
    36  MyApp.iOS                       0x05934141 mono_jit_exec + 198
    37  MyApp.iOS                       0x05a9d174 xamarin_main + 2452
    38  MyApp.iOS                       0x002388bd main + 102
    39  libdyld.dylib                       0x23d0f873 <redacted> + 2
 (Foundation.MonoTouchException)
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowNSException (System.IntPtr ns_exception) [0x00000] in /Library/F
rameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:398 
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception (System.IntPtr exc) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/runtime/Delegates.generated.cs:126 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception(intptr)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at MyApp.iOS.Application.Main (Syst
em.String[] args) [0x00001] in C:\Projects\MyProjects\MyApp\MyApp.iOS\Main.cs:17 
2018-10-18 14:31:47.346 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical: Stacktrace:

2018-10-18 14:31:47.346 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical: 
Native stacktrace:
2018-10-18 14:31:50.337 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  0   MyApp.iOS                       0x05940dfd mono_handle_native_crash + 196
2018-10-18 14:31:50.338 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x23e86077 _sigtramp + 42
2018-10-18 14:31:50.338 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  2   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x23e8c733 pthread_kill + 62
2018-10-18 14:31:50.339 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x23d770ad abort + 108
2018-10-18 14:31:50.339 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  4   MyApp.iOS                       0x05a888b4 xamarin_printf + 0
2018-10-18 14:31:50.339 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  5   MyApp.iOS                       0x0597bf1f mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 102
2018-10-18 14:31:50.340 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  6   MyApp.iOS                       0x0594083b mono_handle_exception_internal + 3750
2018-10-18 14:31:50.340 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  7   MyApp.iOS                       0x0593f991 mono_handle_exception + 50
2018-10-18 14:31:50.341 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  8   MyApp.iOS                       0x05937837 mono_arm_throw_exception + 118
2018-10-18 14:31:50.341 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  9   MyApp.iOS                       0x0085ac4c throw_exception + 64
2018-10-18 14:31:50.341 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  10  MyApp.iOS                       0x05a88390 xamarin_process_managed_exception_gchandle + 60
2018-10-18 14:31:50.342 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  11  MyApp.iOS                       0x05a8834c xamarin_ftnptr_exception_handler + 24
2018-10-18 14:31:50.342 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  12  MyApp.iOS                       0x02bd4f14 wrapper_native_to_managed_ObjCRuntime_Runtime_throw_ns_exception_intptr + 372
2018-10-18 14:31:50.342 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  13  MyApp.iOS                       0x05a86228 xamarin_throw_ns_exception + 52
2018-10-18 14:31:50.343 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  14  MyApp.iOS                       0x05a892b4 _ZL17exception_handlerP11NSException + 288
2018-10-18 14:31:50.344 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  15  CoreFoundation                      0x24157c57 <redacted> + 642
2018-10-18 14:31:50.344 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  16  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x238f309f <redacted> + 174
2018-10-18 14:31:50.344 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  17  libc++abi.dylib                     0x238e4e17 <redacted> + 78
2018-10-18 14:31:50.345 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  18  libc++abi.dylib                     0x238e48f9 __cxa_increment_exception_refcount + 0
2018-10-18 14:31:50.345 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  19  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x238f2f5f objc_exception_rethrow + 42
2018-10-18 14:31:50.345 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  20  CoreFoundation                      0x240672af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 654
2018-10-18 14:31:50.346 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  21  CoreFoundation                      0x24067015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
2018-10-18 14:31:50.346 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  22  GraphicsServices                    0x25657ac9 GSEventRunModal + 160
2018-10-18 14:31:50.347 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  23  UIKit                               0x2873b189 UIApplicationMain + 144
2018-10-18 14:31:50.347 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  24  MyApp.iOS                       0x02bc227c wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 288
2018-10-18 14:31:50.348 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  25  MyApp.iOS                       0x02412044 UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 52
2018-10-18 14:31:50.348 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  26  MyApp.iOS                       0x02411edc UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 200
2018-10-18 14:31:50.349 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  27  MyApp.iOS                       0x0023acb0 MyApp_iOS_Application_Main_string__ + 152
2018-10-18 14:31:50.350 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  28  MyApp.iOS                       0x008014a4 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 232
2018-10-18 14:31:50.351 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  29  MyApp.iOS                       0x0594c9c9 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 824
2018-10-18 14:31:50.351 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  30  MyApp.iOS                       0x059b6eef mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 102
2018-10-18 14:31:50.352 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  31  MyApp.iOS                       0x059bb6db mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 66
2018-10-18 14:31:50.352 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  32  MyApp.iOS                       0x05934141 mono_jit_exec + 198
2018-10-18 14:31:50.352 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  33  MyApp.iOS                       0x05a9d174 xamarin_main + 2452
2018-10-18 14:31:50.353 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  34  MyApp.iOS                       0x002388bd main + 102
2018-10-18 14:31:50.353 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical:  35  libdyld.dylib                       0x23d0f873 <redacted> + 2
2018-10-18 14:31:50.354 MyApp.iOS[319:59406] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
The app has been terminated.
Failed to Stop app:  An error occured on client IDB4110776 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/4.11.0.776/stop-app
The app has been terminated.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521799/trivial-nstimer-scheduledtimerwithtimeintervalrepeatsblock-unrecognized
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method

`public static NSTimer CreateScheduledTimer (double seconds, NSObject target, Selector selector, NSObject userInfo, bool repeats)`

> For Example

```
//...
using ObjCRuntime;
//... 
NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(0.5, this, new Selector("DelayAction"), null, false);

[Export("DelayAction")]
public void DelayAction()
{
  // do some thing you want
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That sounds like how I had it, and it crashes on iOS 9, but not iOS 10 or 11... I was calling the exact same API, NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(). Here is the code:
NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500).Seconds, false, (NSTimer timer) =>
{
    /* Do Work Here... */
});